# Celery SoftTimeLimitExceeded not caught when executing a db transaction

Tags: python, mysql, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a celery task that is being launched with a soft_time_limit.

the entire logic of the task is being surrounded with try except SoftTimeLimitExceeded.

When looking on the logs i can see that celery wrote to the logs

`some_log.log:58232:[2019-10-31 09:19:48,794] [WARNING] [module: job] [logger: celery.worker.job]: Soft time limit (4s) exceeded for project.tasks.some_task[168a4c38-5672-483b-b3cc-dd7c35d85b93]
some_log.log:58235:[2019-10-31 09:19:48,939] [ERROR] [module: base] [logger: sentry.errors.uncaught]: [u'Soft time limit (4s) exceeded for project.tasks.some_task[168a4c38-5672-483b-b3cc-dd7c35d85b93]']`

i'm using:

celery==3.1.15

django-celery==3.1.1

MySQL-python==1.2.5

Python 2.7.16

Mysql 5.7

The task looks something like that:

```
@task(soft_time_limit=4)
def some_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        with MySQLdb.connect(host=host, port=port,
                             user=user, passwd=password,
                             db=name, local_infile=1, autocommit=False) as cursor:
            cursor.execute("update ....")
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
    # handle
```

I tried applying an errorhandler to the connection and to the cursor to raise the exception but still no luck.

It looks as if the process is just being terminated without even raising the exception.

One thing that i tried is launching a new thread that delays the tasks and wait for it to finish.

The thread just surrounded the delay with a try except SoftTimeLimitExceeded and did a get() on the delay.

This thread managed to catch the exception from the task.

```
def thread_delay(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        some_task.delay(args, kwargs).get()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
    # Handle
```

Comment: Do you have to use that old Celery? (That version is over 6 years old)

Comment: Unfortunately yes, this is a legacy system that is EOL but still needs to be maintained

Comment: Adding `time_limit` along with the `soft_time_limit`, raised the exception in my case